# How to determine which IPs in a given range have port 80 using nmap?

Tags: bash, shell, nmap

I'm new to bash scripting and I'm trying to get this working:

Scanning an IP range for finding devices with the port 80 open...
I think it has to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -----------------------------------
for ip in 192.168.0.{1,.255}; do
nmap -p80 192.168.0.1
      if #open; then
            echo "{ip} has the port 80 open"
      else
            #do nothing
fi
done
echo -----------------------------------
exit 0
```

I also just want to see the results like this:

```
-----------------------------------
192.168.0.1 has the port 80 open
192.168.0.10 has the port 80 open
192.168.0.13 has the port 80 open
192.168.0.15 has the port 80 open
-----------------------------------
```

(So without errors or `nmap`'s normal outputs..)

Can someone help me for this?

Comment: You can do this without writing a shellscript. `nmap` supports address ranges and specific port scanning, both as command line arguments. Check out the manpage, or documentation at `nmap.org`.

Comment: You should use nmap options to do what you want. However, here's a little syntax help: `for ip in 192.168.0.{1,255}` (without the extra dot) will give you 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.255 *only*. If you want the range from 1 to 255 inclusive, do this: `for ip in 192.168.0.{1..255}` then your `nmap` command would use this variable: `nmap -p80 "$ip"`

Answer (score 45):

`nmap` comes with a nice output parameter `-oG` (*grepable output*) which makes parsing more easy. Also it is not necessary to iterate through all IP addresses you want to scan. nmap is netmask aware.

Your example can be written as:

```
nmap -p80 192.168.0.0/24 -oG - | grep 80/open
```

The `-oG` enables the *grepable output*, and `-` specifies the file to output to (in this case `stdout`). The pipe symbol redirects the output of nmap (stdout) to grep, which only returns lines containing `80/open` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for you answers...
I sadly don't get an output with your code... I just get these lines (in a shell script):
mass_dns: warning: Unable to open /etc/resolv.conf. Try using--system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns servers
mass_dns: warning Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
And the same lines but with an output in a Term. 
Problem is i want to keep the ip of the device with the open port in a var...

Comment: Is your `/etc/resolv.conf` configured correctly, say it contains at least one valid DNS server? Try using the `-n` switch of nmap, to permanently disable any (reverse) DNS lookups. What do you exacly mean by _keep the IP of the device in a variable_? What is you aim?

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
nmap --open -p80 192.168.0.*
```

The `--open` will only list host with port 80 open. This way you save having to check in your shell script as filtering is already done by nmap itself.

https://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html

Comment: I had to quote this IP address mask but it worked - `nmap --open -p80 "192.168.0.*"`